# How to handle a database in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

We are currently planning a new project which will feature a database with around 10 relations.

I'm not really sure which way we should handle the database data. Currently I'm thinking about using a class for each table and bundle them to a new datatype which I would use for the whole program. If there is an easier/better way, feel free to suggest!

Additionally I'm not entirely sure how to best handle the database connection. Should I read the database every time I need the information, or would it be better to only read when I also made a change on the database.

We will use different threads but only one dbConnection to avoid race-conditions.

Any suggestion concerning this matter would be really welcome!

Comment: (1) Sounds like you want the entity framework (2) `Should I read the database every time I need the information` I don't know how else you'd get the information

Comment: How does this relate to UML?

Comment: @Jonesy Thank you very much for your help, sadly I can't upvote your input

Comment: @Uffe Well we are currently in the planning phase of this project and I thought the topic was related to different design pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using Entity Framework
See this article for more information http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/426790/Using-MySQL-with-Entity-Framework

Answer (score 0):

It is completely based on your system needs,

Entity Framework is good for enterprise solutions, if you are having small db with limited information, it is better to write your own DAL with `DataReader`(it gives better performance over `DataSet`)

If your system is like mid range enterprise, you can look for Linq2SQL